# OS X objective c Drag and Drop text inside textfield to change the order

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, nstextfield, nstextview

I wanted separation and drag and drop of text inside NSTextfield or NSTextview. Please find  sample of this in Mac System Preferences-> Language & Region -> Advanced ->Dates
Screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `NSTokenField`.

Comment: Thanks. Its working for me.